# Is it possible to force Cells.find to exclude a sheet from its search?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create a function that returns the adress of a given value. I have come as far as making a search function that returns the adress, however I do not know how to exclude the sheet that the function will be used in. My code so far is given below.

Ideally I want to look up a value in the second or third sheet (whereever it is written) and return its adress, which I can then use to find the values given next to the searched word using indirect.

I have tried using some build in functions such as INDEX(MATCH(, however as I do not know the match column this does not provide any results.

```
Public Function SuperSearch(SVal As String)
    Dim FVal As Range
        Set FVal = Cells.Find(What:=SVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If FVal Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Not Found")
            Else
            SuperSearch = ra.Address
            End If
End Function
```

When I run the above function I am simply given the value I used in my search:

```
       A                   B
```

1
2   FindMeImHelpFull    =SuperSearch(A2)
3

Returns

```
       A                   B
```

1
2   FindMeImHelpFull          A$2$
3

I would like it to return the string FindMeImHelpFull in sheet2 on H15 instead giving me:

```
       A                   B
```

1
2   FindMeImHelpFull       Sheet2!H$15$
3

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Can you let us know what `ra` means in your code -> `ra.Address`

Answer (score 0):

Just perform the search on a specific sheet:

```
Public Function SuperSearch(sheetname As String, SVal As String) As String
    Dim FVal As Range
    Set FVal = Sheets(sheetname).Cells.Find(What:=SVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If FVal Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Not Found")
    Else
        SuperSearch = FVal.Address
    End If
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

**Interesting Resource:**

[Arron Blood](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/tip-tricks-code/17729-kickbutt-vba-find-function?t=27240)

Comment: This. Or if the search result is on the sheet you want to exclude, keep searching until there's no result or one is found on a sheet you don't want to exclude

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  You are correct!, but then the open issue is: On which sheet was the data found??

Comment: Really what OP should do is return the value given next to the word sought instead of using the result of this UDF in INDIRECT.

Comment: I'd use `Range.Parent` to get the sheet the found range belongs to